# One Long module vs Multiple Short modules Code-Splitting

Tags: javascript

I started prototyping my `modules` inside the `src` folder for a Javascript `package`.

but I'm wondering which strategy would be better for the developers to use the package for production.

**First strategy** :

```
src
 |---scripts
        |-----comparator.js
```

Inside `comparator.js` I put all functions that handle comparison.

```
  export function lessThan(array){...}

  export function BigThan(array){...}

  export function equalTo(array){...}
  
  .....
```

I have many `lessThan`, many `BigThan` and so on.

**Second Strategy** :

```
      src
       |---scripts
              |---comparator
                        |---------less.js
                        |---------big.js
                        |---------equal.js
```

- How do I separate my `modules` inside `src` folder?
- How to measure the module performance?

Answer (score 1):

I think the **second strategy** would be better in terms of overall performance.

This would enable better **tree shaking**, even in cases when these modules are being consumed along with codebases that do not support proper **dynamic imports**. Most frameworks do not treat code splitting as first-class citizens. Often there is not enough support on browsers as well. In those cases, developers may have to rely on polyfills or bundlers like Webpack which provides some of this functionality (import() or require.ensure()). Often in these cases, tree shaking cannot be done even if one only requires a certain named export. The entire default export would have to be used, which is a waste of resources (time being the most critical one - download and parse time).

So I would recommend all the critical and mandatory functionality into one file. Anything else which is optional and can be modularized can be placed into separate files and exported individually.

**Performance Measurement:**
For measuring the performance of APIs, one can use **Node** (since it uses V8) along with some options such as '--prof'.

```
    node --prof filename.js
```

This needs to be done several times as one optimizes or micro-optimized the code. There are several other options that can be used to ensure lazy and eager execution of different parts of your code.

One can also use the **performance API** to mark and measure various stages of the API execution using both Browsers as well as Node. That being said the V8 options that can be used with Node can give you a lot of information for optimization.

For load time optimization, I would recommend proper code-splitting (as mentioned above) and trial across different browsers (there can be slightly different behavior across various browsers)